# shows "Connection Timed Out" on tor

Tags: configuration, error, connection

I can't surf in tor to see deep websites. it shows , "Connection Timed Out". Here is my tor log.

27-03-2017 12:15:45.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
27-03-2017 12:15:46.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
27-03-2017 12:15:48.300 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
27-03-2017 12:15:48.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
27-03-2017 12:15:49.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
27-03-2017 12:15:49.300 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Do you get that error for all sites? Try Tor Projects .onion addresses: https://onion.torproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

The "Connection Timed Out" is shown by Tor Browser in case it can't reach a page. It generally indicates the site isn't available rather than that Tor isn't set up properly.

To ensure that Tor is working go to https://check.torproject.org. If you want to verify that you can reach .onion addresses try one of addresses listed on https://onion.torproject.org/ or on https://onion.debian.org/. The addresses on these lists are pretty reliable.